# Joint discrete probabilities

Tags: statistics

I want to find out the expected value E[ABC].

- When B takes on 0, A takes on 0.5
- When C takes on 0, A takes on 0.1
- B and C cannot both take on 0

A takes on two values:

- 0.5 - 80% of the time
- 0.1 - 20% of the time

B takes on two values:

- 1 - 60% of the time and
- 0 - 40% of the time

C takes on two values:

- 1 - 90% of the time and
- 0 - 10% of the time

Any simplification in this problem would be appreciated. I am very confused and don't know where to start.

Comment: There are only 8 combinations of outcomes (with several not being possible), so best tactic is to write them all out, along with the associated value for ABC, determine the probabilities, and calculate the expected value directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(A=0.5,B=1,C=1)=0.4 ABC=0.5

P(A=0.5,B=1,C=0)=0

P(A=0.5,B=0,C=1)=0.4 ABC=0

P(A=0.5,B=0,C=0)=0

P(A=0.1,B=1,C=1)=0.1 ABC=0.1

P(A=0.1,B=1,C=0)=0.1 ABC=0

P(A=0.1,B=0,C=1)=0

P(A=0.1,B=0,C=0)=0

Calculating the expected value directly, E(ABC)=0.21

Comment: How did you figure out the non-zero probabilities? For example why is P(A=0.5,B=1,C=1)?

Comment: Figured it out, you set up a system of equations so that each combination where say A was 0.5 had to sum up to 0.8.

Comment: @SamBaker, correct.